# Laravel collection transform unset element

Tags: php, laravel, collections, transform

Am I able to unset whole collection element inside transform?

```
$jsonArrLive->transform(function ($i,$k) {
            $test = $i[0]->some ?? null;
            if(!$test) {
                return null;
            }
      $i['test'] = 'test'; 
      //and other transform code
}
```

Now i get `['arr1=>..',null]` and I want to remove this null inside transform to get just `['arr1=>..']` as result

I added:

```
    $jsonArrLive = $jsonArrLive->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value != null;
    });
```

and I have expected result but is this possible to do this inside transform?

Comment: You can't remove elements via transform, but why don't you like `filter` function?

Comment: Because I'm duplicating code now I have two loops instead of one :)

Comment: `$jsonArrLive = $jsonArrLive->filter(function ($value, $key) {return $i[0]->some;});` If you need just remove such items you can use only `filter`

Comment: I'm also didn't mention that i have a lot of other code to of course transform the collection  inside this transform function but to keep question clean i showed it like that

Comment: ok, to solve it just use ordinary `foreach`. You can change and remove elements inside it